I am trying to filter my offer post type by hotel slug but it is rendering empty array
Hi guys i am trying to filter my offer post type by hotel slug which is connected through acf relationship field type this is my function but it is rendering empty array via graphql
ACF STRUCTURE enter image description here
 add_action('graphql_register_types', function () {
    // Registering a new 'hotelSlug' field to filter the promotions and offers by the hotel slug
    register_graphql_field('RootQueryToPromotionAndOfferConnectionWhereArgs', 'hotelSlug', [
        'type' => 'String',
        'description' => 'Filter promotions and offers by the associated hotel slug',
    ]);
});

add_filter('graphql_post_object_connection_query_args', function ($query_args, $source, $args, $context, $info) {
    // Ensure we are modifying the right query (i.e., promotions and offers)
    if (isset($info->fieldName) && 'promotionsAndOffers' === $info->fieldName) {
        // Check if hotelSlug is part of the GraphQL query arguments
        if (!empty($args['where']['hotelSlug'])) {
            // Find the hotel post by its slug
            $hotelPost = get_posts([
                'name' => sanitize_text_field($args['where']['hotelSlug']),
                'post_type' => 'hotel',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'numberposts' => 1
            ]);

            // If the hotel post is found
            if (!empty($hotelPost)) {
                $hotelPostId = $hotelPost[0]->ID;

                // ACF stores post object selections as serialized data, but we're looking for the ID within that serialization
                // The following meta query searches for the string representation of the hotel post ID within the serialized array
                $query_args['meta_query'][] = [
                    'key' => 'participating_hotels_%_select_hotel',
                    'value' => '"' . $hotelPostId . '"', // The quotes are necessary for a LIKE match within serialized data
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $query_args;
}, 10, 5);

